# AWS Data Pipeline S3 CSV to DynamoDB JSON Error

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-data-pipeline, aws-data-pipeline

I'm trying to insert several csv located in the S3 directory with the AWS DATA Pipeline But, I'm taking this error.

at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1844) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:169) Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected ':' at line 1 column 10 at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1505) at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:519) at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:414) at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157) at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40) at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:187) at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145) at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803) ... 15 more Exception in thread "main" java.io.
errorStackTrace
amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskExecutionException: Failed to complete EMR transform. at amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.EmrActivity.runActivity(EmrActivity.java:67) at amazonaws.datapipeline.objects.AbstractActivity.run(AbstractActivity.java:16) at amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller.executeRemoteRunner(TaskPoller.java:136) at amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller.executeTask(TaskPoller.java:105) at amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller$1.run(TaskPoller.java:81) at private.com.amazonaws.services.datapipeline.poller.PollWorker.executeWork(PollWorker.java:76) at private.com.amazonaws.services.datapipeline.poller.PollWorker.run(PollWorker.java:53) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskExecutionException: at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1844) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:169) Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected ':' at line 1 column 10 at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1505) at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:519) at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:414) at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157) at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40) at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:187) at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145) at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803) ... 15 more Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed! at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:873) at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.tools.DynamoDBImport.run(DynamoDBImport.java:81) at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76) at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.tools.DynamoDBImport.main(DynamoDBImport.java:43) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:239) at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:153) at amazonaws.datapipeline.cluster.EmrUtil.runSteps(EmrUtil.java:286) at amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.EmrActivity.runActivity(EmrActivity.java:63) ... 7 more

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem.

format that the AWS DATA Pipeline uses.

````
{"Name": {"S":"Amazon push"},"Category": {"S":"Amazon Web Services"}}
{"Name": {"S":"Amazon S3"},"Category": {"S":"Amazon Web Services"}}```

References:

https://calorious.wordpress.com/2016/03/18/episode-4-importing-json-into-dynamodb/

https://medium.com/@ashleywnj/appsync-s3-data-pipeline-dynamodb-854f99d70b41
````